# qsub disregarded memory limit

Tags: memory, pbs, qsub

My command is:

```
qsub -t 1:30:1 -q test.q -l r_core=5 -l r_mem=30 run.sh
```

It launches 30 instances, each on one server, but they tend to consume more than the specified 30GB of RAM.

What are the reasons for this?

Comment: I don't recognize r_core and r_mem. Is this a custom branch? What's the resource manager flavor? Also, what scheduler do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The only real-time resource enforcement you get is A) checking of min/max requests at submission, and B) walltime--and even with walltime, you may not get reliable enforcement, depending on the node. For solid resource enforcement, you should impose default resource restrictions, and then upgrade to the version supporting cgroups and enable that.